# Qt Test QVERIFY2() string and int concatenation

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qt4, qtestlib

Sorry for the bad title, I have no idea how to title this question.  Please edit and make it better.

I am writing a test using the Qt test framework, and I'm trying to write some useful output to be used by the `QVERIFY2()` macro. All of the following statements have failed to compile with roughly the same error message:

```
QVERIFY2( spy.count() == 1, "Emitted signal pathChanged() was emitted " + spy.count() + " times instead of 1 time" );
QVERIFY2( spy.count() == 1, QString( "Emitted signal pathChanged() was emitted " ) + QString( spy.count() ) + QString( " times instead of 1 time" ) );
QVERIFY2( spy.count() == 1, "Emitted signal pathChanged() was emitted " + QString( spy.count() ) + " times instead of 1 time" );
```

The error message for the last attempt was:

```
PathTester.cxx: In member function ‘void PathTester::testReservePath()’:
PathTester.cxx:241:128: error: cannot convert ‘QString’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘bool QTest::qVerify(bool, const char*, const char*, const char*, int)’
PathTester.cxx:241:243: error: cannot convert ‘QString’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘bool QTest::qVerify(bool, const char*, const char*, const char*, int)’
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I write that correctly?

Comment: It wants a const char* and not a QString...

Comment: The output that you pasted looks extremely fishy -- namely, the opening round bracket `FAIL!  : PathTester::testPath() '(` <-- here. Is it really that way? Also, what does `expectedNum` contain at that point (dump it just before the verify), and why isn't it in the test itself?

Comment: @peppe You're right, it was fishy.  That `(` was not there in the code (must have added it unintentionally??)  Fortunately, when I went back to look at the original I realized that I was reading the output from a copy/pasted line that wasn't updated with `QString::number()` \*sigh\*.  Looks like it was a hardware failure between the chair and the keyboard :-)  It's one of those days...  I removed the boneheadedness from the question.  Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `QVERIFY2(condition, qPrintable(...))` when using a QString.

The second argument *must be* a `const char *`. In all of your cases you're creating a QString instead -- which is indeed very convenient because it allows you to use `+` for concatenation, or `QString::arg()`, etc; you need a conversion to `char *`, which is not implicit, and that's what `qPrintable()` does.

<sub>To elaborate: `qPrintable(string)` is a shorthand for `string.toLocal8Bit().constData()`. Qt 5.4 will also introduce `qUtf8Printable(string)` which is the equivalent of `string.toUtf8().constData()`.</sub>

**Addendum:** apart from the technicality of what to pass to `QVERIFY2`, why aren't you using `QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 1)`? In case of failure it will emit the expected value and the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my 5 cents. While you actually may use QCOMPARE in your specific case as @peppe suggested, sometimes you may need to provide a more detailed message. That the case for QVERIFY2. The best way for formatting message in this case that I know is exploitation of QString::arg() method. For example in you case you could write:

```
QVERIFY2 (
    spy.count() == 1, 
    qPrintable (
        QString ("Emitted signal pathChanged() was emitted %1 times instead of %2 time(s)")
        .arg (spy.count())
        .arg (1)));
```

This way you get a more readable code and may change both actual count and expected count expressions.